# Which of the following are not globally based AWS services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I was going through the AWS Cloud practitioner study guide (CLF-C01), and I think the answer should be the opposite of what they described.
Route 53 and CloudFront have globally based AWS services so the answers should be A, C, right?

Following is Q&A from the study guide

Q. Which of the following are not globally based AWS services? (Select TWO.) 
A. RDS 
B. Route 53 
C. EC2 
D. CloudFront \

Explanation: B, D. Relational Database Service (RDS) and EC2 both use resources that can exist in only
one Region. Route 53 and CloudFront are truly global services in that they’re not located in
or restricted to any single AWS Region.

Comment: It looks like this is an error. Which study guide is it? An official one by AWS or a third party publication or website?

Comment: FYI, AWS will never ask a 'negative' question (eg "Which is NOT..."). This is because it is easily misunderstood and the certification exams aim to test the _technical knowledge_ of students rather than their reading ability. Additionally, any "Choose TWO" questions will always have five available answers (choose 2 of 5).

Comment: @DennisTraub, it is not official documentation but widely known. AWS Certified Cloud Practitioner study guide by BEN PIPER and DAVID CLINTON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- EC2 and RDS are regional services.
- Route53 and CloudFront are global services.

The correct answer is A and C

Comment: Yes! so the answer should be A, C right? (In the Study guide it is B, D)

Comment: Correct. They missed the *not* in the question I think